# Same query but different results in phpMyAdmin and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have seen similar posts to this one already existing but none of them have helped.

When I run this PHP code with $retrievestat = 1, I get a value of 1 return by the search query in php:

```
$retrievestat = $_POST["statIdentifier"];
echo $retrievestat;

// Retrieve The Player With The Most Rounds Won With Their Rounds
if ($retrievestat == 1)
{
    $checkuniquequery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM playerstats WHERE roundswon = (SELECT MAX(roundswon) FROM playerstats);";  // Get number of rows that have a roundswon value equal to the max in the table
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($checkuniquequery);
    echo ($stmt->execute());
    if ($stmt->execute() == 1)  // If only one row has the max roundswon then get the username + roundswon
    {
        $mostroundswonquery = "SELECT username, MAX(roundswon) FROM players, playerstats WHERE players.id = playerstats.id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($mostroundswonquery);
        //echo ($stmt->execute());
    }
```

However, when I run this query in phpMyAdmin:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM playerstats WHERE roundswon = (SELECT MAX(roundswon) FROM playerstats);"
```

I get 2 returned as the output.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you made sure that `->execute()` returns the actual count and not "_true on success or false on failure_"?

Answer (score 1):

The execute method on PDO statement (`$stmt->execute()`) does return either true (if execution was successful) or false if not. It **does not** return the return value of the SQL statement. On a side node: `$stmt->execute() == 1` does behave the same as `$stmt->execute() == true` !

To get the actual return value you need to fetch the result after execution.
E.g. you can use `$stmt->fetch()` to get actual result.

Have a look at the documentation to learn more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php